# Why does ajax response Preview section show increased font size html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Please tell why does AJAX response previews show increased font sized html?
when I assign this html to some div, it shows up normally as any in page html would.

Is it any bug in Chrome Extension?

[image: Ajax response with html as a part of JSON]

And the post raw response is:

[image: the raw respons in json is as follows]

```
{"form_key":{"status":"true"},"filter":{"status":"true","msg":"Success","data":"<div class=\"detailsPanel active\"><div class=\"collapsePanel\"><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>Voice<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>00:00:00<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2 class=\"manat_sign\">0.00<\/h2><\/div><\/div><div class=\"collapseDrop\"><\/div><\/div><div class=\"detailsPanel \"><div class=\"collapsePanel\"><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>SMS<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>0<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2 class=\"manat_sign\">0.00<\/h2><\/div><\/div><div class=\"collapseDrop\"><\/div><\/div><div class=\"detailsPanel \"><div class=\"collapsePanel\"><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>Internet<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>0<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2 class=\"manat_sign\">0.00<\/h2><\/div><\/div><div class=\"collapseDrop\"><\/div><\/div><div class=\"detailsPanel \"><div class=\"collapsePanel\"><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>Other<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2>0.0<\/h2><\/div><div class=\"detailHeading\"><h2 class=\"manat_sign\">0.0<\/h2><\/div><\/div><div class=\"collapseDrop\"><\/div><\/div>"}}
```

Comment: I don't think it is the AJAX response per say, but rather Chromes Preview

Comment: post raw response as well please.

Comment: This is obviously a bug. It should be fixed in the next version. Use Chrome Canary meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The response is probably using `em` to size the text. This will add a cumulative increase in size if the text is always wrapped in another layer down.

Comment: if the response is wrapped, then the whole json should appear like this.. why only html section?

Comment: Because its rendering the html as html not as json data.